# Turn off logging of Solr in "sbt test"

Tags: scala, logging, solr, sbt

I am using Solr in Scala. I have a test case that adds some documents into Solr core.

When running `sbt test`, the following information is shown repeatedly:

`15/12/03 01:17:50 INFO LogUpdateProcessor: [test] webapp=null path=/update params={} {add=[(null)]} 0 2`

In an attempt to suppress it, I put a `log4j.properties` with content:

`.level=WARNING
org.apache.solr.core.level=WARNING
org.apache.solr.update.processor.level=WARNING`

under both `${project_dir}/src/main/resources` and `${project_dir}/src/test/resources`

However, the log message is still there.

I am using :

- Scala 2.11.5
- solr-solrj 5.3.1
- solr-core 5.3.1
- sbt 0.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The `log4j.properties` file is malformatted.

The following content works:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n>
```